# How to interpret results from Zero-inflated negative binomial?

Tags: regression

I used Zero-inflated negative binomial, to see the Black-headed gull abundance by the Presence of raptors and Dogs, I have got the following results, how to interpret these results???
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please can you edit your question and post the output itself, rather than a picture of it.

Comment: The intercepts are both extremely high, the estimates for the covariates are very low in comparison, and theta is also very low. Are you sure you have zero inflation, and what is the scale of the outcome - can you post a histogram of it ?

Comment: What does the plot show?  Without labels or explanation it's difficult to tell.

Comment: Robert Long, thanks for your comment, I have posted a histogram above there are many zeros. Please can you provide your mail ID so I can contact you directly?

Comment: *Please can you edit your question and post the output itself, rather than a picture of it*

Comment: Also, please can you include the output of `str(E)`